# Create DB from scratch using dump without system tablespace

Tags: oracle11g, dump, tablespace, automatic-storage

i have this scenario:

Oracle 11g with ASM.

Some days ago the disk where there were system's tablespace datafiles got broken and there is no way to recover them.

I had a dump, made with "exp", of all data from all owner, except system user.
Could i format all devices and recreate asm_disksgroup and asm_disks and import my dump ?
Is there a way to recreate DB from scratch using that dump without system data?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. After recreating asm diskgroup, you can create an empty database and import exp dump to reload your data. system user data will be populated while data being loaded